# How to use vectors efficiently?

Tags: c++, vector

I am using vectors and vector size_type in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

typedef vector<int>::size_type size_type;

int main()
{
    size_type n; 
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> u(n,0);
    for(size_type i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
      cin >> u[i];
    }
    cout << *u.end();

    return 0;
}
```

The bug is that when I input n=5. The vectors asks for 5 elements and then prints out 0 or some garbage value. 
How do I print the last element?

Comment: what has this to do with efficiency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`u.end()` is an iterator that can't be dereferenced (so called "past the end iterator"). Use `u.back()` to get the last value.

Answer (score 5):

The bug is here:

```
cout<<*u.end();
```

The `end()` iterator points to the element one past the end of the vector. Dereferencing it is always undefined behavior.

If you have an `end()` iterator and you wish to see the last element, use [`std::prev`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/), like this:

```
cout << *std::prev(u.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

`u.end()` gives an iterator pointing beyond the last element; you'd have to decrement it to point to the last element. You can't dereference the past-the end iterator; trying to do so gives undefined behaviour.

The last element is available as `u.back()`.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed thiis statement

```
cout<<*u.end();
```

results in printing the garbage value. The iterator returned by member function end() "points" to after the last actual element in the container.

It is the same as in the loop

```
for(size_type i=0; i!=n; ++i)
```

where the value of n is excluded from the loop. You could rewrite the loop the following way

```
for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = u.begin(); it != u.end(); ++it )
```

In fact `u.end()` is equal to `u.begin() + n`If n is not an acceptable index then `u.begin() + n`is not an iterator that may be dereferenced.